# Spring filter not able to bypass certain request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityTokenConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
        // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to store user's state.
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)     
    .and()
        // handle an authorized attempts 
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))  
    .and()
       // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
       .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    // authorization requests config
    .authorizeRequests()
       // allow all who are accessing "auth" service
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/${basePath:/}${version:/}/session/**").permitAll()  
       // must be an admin if trying to access admin area (authentication is also required here)
       // Any other request must be authenticated
       .anyRequest().authenticated(); 

}
```

}

The above filter is not able to allow /session request to bypass 'JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter'.

Anybody knows what's the problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in another way by overriding the `configure(WebSecurity)` method like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("**/session/**");
}
```

And remove the `antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/${basePath:/}${version:/}/session/**").permitAll()`

Comment: No it is still going to that Filter